# comparing todays date + 30 days to another date

Tags: java, date

I'm trying an example:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String date = "03/09/2010"; //30 days from today
Date usefullDate = df.parse(date);

Calendar todaysDatePlus30Days = Calendar.getInstance();
todaysDatePlus30Days.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 30);

System.out.println ("Compared Value: " +
usefullDate.compareTo(todaysDatePlus30Days.getTime()))
```

the printed value is `-1`.  why is it not printing `0`?

I think the problem is that `todaysDatePlus30Days.getTime()` is bringing the actual time as well. whereas `usefullDate`'s time is `00:00:00`.

So next question is how can I just get the `date`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date you parse is implicitly midnight of that date.  The one you construct will be the current time of day.

Try:

```
Calendar todayPlus30 = new GregorianCalendar() {{
  add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 30);
  set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
  set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
  set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
}};
```

*I might have a couple of those constants wrong, and you can do this with Calendar.newInstance() if you like, though the syntax is a little different.*

Comment: Your cause is right on, but you can't subclass a return value like that. You will have to keep a reference and call the sets on that reference, or use `new GregorianCalendar(){{`

Comment: Oh right, sorry; I always use GregorianCalendar and I just typed in robot mode :-)

Answer (score 3):

As a further comment, I would investigate [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for all date-related Java work. It's much more intuitive, and doesn't suffer from threading problems in the date/time formatting and parsing classes (unlike the standard Java libraries). Nowadays it's a *de facto* replacement for the `java.util.{Date,Calendar}` mess.

e.g. see the [LocalDate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class and its `plusDays()` method.

Answer (score 1):

When you `System.out.println(..)` them, the result is:

```
Tue Mar 09 00:00:00 EET 2010
Tue Mar 09 20:31:39 EET 2010
```

So they are not equal - their hours differ. This is because `Calendar.getInstance()` returns the current date *and* time.

If you want them to be equal, you'll have to `set(..)` the hours, minutes and seconds fields to 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the following lines to your example, you will learn that useful Date has a different time

```
System.out.println ("" + usefullDate );
System.out.println ("" + todaysDatePlus30Days.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using JodaTime, but if you use long for date/time you can do...

```
long todaysDay = System.currentTimeMillis() / MILLIS_PER_DAY;
long in30days = todaysDay + 30;
long usefulDay = usefulDate.getTime() / MILLIS_PER_DAY;
if (in30days == usefulDay) // days are the same.
```

Note: the performs calculations as per GMT+0 timezone. This can make a difference.